# Многострочный ввод в REPL

Tags: coffeescript, javascript, консоль

coffeescript - многострочный ввод в REPL с обратным слешем:

```
coffee> add = (x, y)->\
[stdin]:1:15: error: unexpected \
add = (x, y)->\
              ^
coffee>
```

Почему не работает?

Comment: @Андрей Титов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

А разве должно так работать? Это же только в скриптах так можно, а в REPL через ctrl+V включается многострочный режим.

Comment: Как быть с примером из книги http://books.google.ru/books?id=nPlQAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&hl=ru&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q&f=false на стр.32-33?

Comment: Единственное, что приходит в голову, так это то, что ответ содержится на странице 27 той же книги, а также в самом начале официальной страницы http://coffeescript.org/